# 24v vs 48v solar inverter

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, inverter

I have 4 batteries of 150AH each. Earlier these were connected as series to 48v solar inverter of 3000 Watts, now as that old inverter is dead and I need to replace it with new one. I want to know which inverter is better

```
24v Inverter with 4 batteries in parallel of 2
or
48v Inverter with 4 battereies in series
```

What are the benefits in term of charging time, backup etc

Note: 48v is costly as compare to 24v

Comment: How many Watts is the inverter?

Comment: What voltage are your batteries? If they are 12V then you connect the 4 batteries in _series_ to get 48V, and in series/parallel to get 24V.

Comment: @BruceAbbot Yes u r right, I updated the question

Comment: @mkeith 3000 Watts

Comment: Bruce Abbot's answer pretty much covers it. I agree 100% with him. And that is why I asked about the power rating.

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of 48V over 24V is that only half as much current is required to get the same power. Assuming 95% converter efficiency, for 3kW output at 24V your battery wiring has to handle 132A! At 48V it drops to a more reasonable 66A. This is actually better than you might think because power loss is proportional to current *squared*, so if you use your existing wiring and connectors the loss in them will be 4 times higher.

A 24V inverter might be a bit cheaper, but you should consider the cost of replacing your wiring and fuses etc. You should also consider that a cheap 24V inverter might not be as reliable as a higher quality 48V unit.